# PHP reset $_SESSION in all devices if $_SESSION is equal to some value

Tags: php, session

How can I do the following idea in all devices?

```
if($_SESSION["ID"] == 1)
     $_SESSION["ID"] = null;
```

For example, device A,B,C has `$_SESSION["ID"] == 1` while device D has `$_SESSION["ID"] == 2`. I want to reset `$_SESSION["ID"]` (`$_SESSION["ID"] = null`) in device A,B,C. How can I do so?

Comment: Put session_start() on the top of your code. For devices assign different credentials, let users login from there, or provide an entering url, so that you can differentiate among devices. Or better, if it is only 3 well-known devices you use, you can see user_agent string they generate, and distinguish like that.

Comment: If I don't know which device has $_SESSION["ID"] == 1? How can I do?

Comment: Read my comment above.

Comment: Can you write some simple code to differentiate different devices. Also, after I know which device, how to reset their sessions as different devices have their sessions and device A Connot manipulate other

Comment: To reset session just call session_destroy(), all session data will be destroyed. To help you, you need to be more specific with your question, what decices are you talking about? How many? Will they change in time? Edit your question with this data. Why not make users login?

Comment: Yes, I make users to login. But, if the user have already login and I delete the user record in database, then I want to force the user to logout. So, I need to reset his session. So, how can I reset his session from my computer?

Comment: Add `session_destroy()` line on the top of a file you want, it will force all sessions destroyed - when that file is accessed. I wrote you this earlier, read my comments.

Comment: session_destroy() is for destroy() the session when the page is loaded. However, when the user loads the page already before I delete the user, the session is still there. I want to force his device to destroy() the session once I delete the user.